# Не отображается админ. консоль в wildfly

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly

Я скачал Wildfly 8.2.1 Final с оф. сайта. Разархивировал, запустил сервер с помощью standalone.bat. localhost:8080 отображается нормально. Потом добавил нового юзера с помощью add-user.bat. Захотел зайти в админ. консоль localhost:9990. Ничего не отображается, просто пустая вкладка. Порты пересмотрел. Ничего не использует порт 9990.

Но сначала было все нормально. Я сначала скачал версию Wildfly 8.0.0 проделал все выше сказанное и консоль отображалась. Потом я захотел сконфигурировать сервер в eclipse. Сделал все как нужно. И потом вкладка перестала отображаться. Потом я уже переустановил wildfly на более новую версию, убрал сервер из eclipse, но увы, ничего не поменялось

Есть только внешний адрес 1-╧╩:9990, который использует chrome.exe, но он же не должен никак влиять на программы на моем компьютере, ведь он внешний.

Логи:

```
   2015-11-01 20:37:26,302 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.3.Final
   2015-11-01 20:37:26,744 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.2.Final
   2015-11-01 20:37:26,857 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.2.1.Final "Tweek" starting
   2015-11-01 20:37:26,868 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-1)   Configured system properties:
   awt.toolkit = sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
file.encoding = Cp1251
file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
file.separator = \
java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
java.awt.printerjob = sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
java.class.path = D:\WildFly\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\jboss-modules.jar
java.class.version = 52.0
java.endorsed.dirs = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\endorsed
java.ext.dirs = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext
java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre
java.io.tmpdir = C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Temp\
java.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\db\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;C:\Inprise\vbroker\bin;D:\C__BUI~1\Bin;D:\C__BUI~1\Projects\Bpl;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;.
java.net.preferIPv4Stack = true
java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_65-b17
java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version = 1.8
java.util.logging.manager = org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
java.version = 1.8.0_65
java.vm.info = mixed mode
java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version = 25.65-b01
javax.management.builder.initial = org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder
javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory = __redirected.__DatatypeFactory
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory = __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory
javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory = __redirected.__SAXParserFactory
javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory = __redirected.__XMLEventFactory
javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory = __redirected.__XMLInputFactory
javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory = __redirected.__XMLOutputFactory
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = __redirected.__TransformerFactory
javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema = __redirected.__SchemaFactory
javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom = __redirected.__XPathFactory
jboss.home.dir = D:\WildFly\wildfly-8.2.1.Final
jboss.host.name = 1-пк
jboss.modules.dir = D:\WildFly\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\modules
jboss.modules.system.pkgs = org.jboss.byteman
jboss.node.name = 1-пк
jboss.qualified.host.name = 1-пк
jboss.server.base.dir = D:\WildFly\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone
jboss.server.config.dir = D:\WildFly\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\configuration
jboss.server.data.dir = D:\WildFly\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\data
jboss.server.deploy.dir = D:\WildFly\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\data\content
jboss.server.log.dir = D:\WildFly\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\log
jboss.server.name = 1-пк
jboss.server.persist.config = true
jboss.server.temp.dir = D:\WildFly\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\tmp
line.separator = 

logging.configuration = file:D:\WildFly\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\configuration/logging.properties
module.path = D:\WildFly\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\modules
org.jboss.boot.log.file = D:\WildFly\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\log\server.log
org.jboss.resolver.warning = true
org.xml.sax.driver = __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory
os.arch = amd64
os.name = Windows 7
os.version = 6.1
path.separator = ;
program.name = standalone.bat
sun.arch.data.model = 64
sun.boot.class.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\classes
sun.boot.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin
sun.cpu.endian = little
sun.cpu.isalist = amd64
sun.desktop = windows
sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
sun.java.command = D:\WildFly\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\jboss-modules.jar -mp D:\WildFly\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=D:\WildFly\wildfly-8.2.1.Final
sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
sun.jnu.encoding = Cp1251
sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
sun.os.patch.level = 
sun.stderr.encoding = cp866
sun.stdout.encoding = cp866
user.country = RU
user.country.format = US
user.dir = D:\WildFly\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\bin
user.home = C:\Users\1
user.language = ru
user.language.format = en
user.name = 1
user.script = 
user.timezone = Europe/Helsinki
user.variant = 
2015-11-01 20:37:26,870 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) VM Arguments: -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=D:\WildFly\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\log\server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:D:\WildFly\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\configuration/logging.properties 
  2015-11-01 20:37:30,071 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
  2015-11-01 20:37:30,227 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
  2015-11-01 20:37:30,342 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
  2015-11-01 20:37:30,410 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS010153: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
  2015-11-01 20:37:30,412 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
  2015-11-01 20:37:30,473 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.1.9.Final)
  2015-11-01 20:37:30,505 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
  2015-11-01 20:37:30,566 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 4 core threads with 32 task threads based on your 2 available processors
  2015-11-01 20:37:30,608 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS012615: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
  2015-11-01 20:37:30,725 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO version 3.3.0.Final
  2015-11-01 20:37:30,751 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.0.Final
  2015-11-01 20:37:30,848 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.1.8.Final starting
  2015-11-01 20:37:31,044 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.21.Final
  2015-11-01 20:37:31,086 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
  2015-11-01 20:37:31,256 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBAS017527: Creating file handler for path D:\WildFly\wildfly-8.2.1.Final/welcome-content
  2015-11-01 20:37:31,997 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.1.8.Final starting
  2015-11-01 20:37:32,112 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.7.Final
  2015-11-01 20:37:32,115 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
  2015-11-01 20:37:32,191 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
  2015-11-01 20:37:32,252 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
  2015-11-01 20:37:32,329 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017525: Started server default-server.
  2015-11-01 20:37:32,331 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory D:\WildFly\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\deployments
  2015-11-01 20:37:32,352 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017531: Host default-host starting
  2015-11-01 20:37:32,447 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017519: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on /127.0.0.1:8080
  2015-11-01 20:37:32,894 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
   2015-11-01 20:37:33,269 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.3.2.Final
  2015-11-01 20:37:33,579 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
  2015-11-01 20:37:33,583 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
  2015-11-01 20:37:33,584 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: WildFly 8.2.1.Final "Tweek" started in 7700ms - Started 184 of 234 services (82 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: Есть ли в логах какие-то ошибки или варнинги? Пробовали прибить хром?

Comment: Нет, в логах все нормально и тот хром уже пропал, хотя сам браузер активен.

Answer (score 1):

Попробовал зайти на админ. консоль с помощью не localhost, а 127.0.0.1:9990 и все заработало.

Comment: скорее всего запускали без опции -b <ip>, он тогда биндит на 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Для Standalone конфигурации интерфейсы для доступа к админке настраиваются в файле 
`wildfly/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`:

```
<interfaces>
  ...
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
  ...
</interfaces>
```

по дефолту там 127.0.0.1, можете заменить на доступ с любых интерфейсов: `0.0.0.0`, либо сделать переопределение параметров запуска Wildfly

```
-Djboss.bind.address.management=требуемый_ip
```